# How to Open the link in new tab

Tags: javascript, asp.net, tabs, new-operator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Programmatically open new pages on Tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/427479/programmatically-open-new-pages-on-tabs)

I have a link in my page and i want it to be opened in a new tab when the user clicks it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Programmatically open new pages on Tabs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/427479/programmatically-open-new-pages-on-tabs) Sadly the answer hasn't chnaged since then (Jan '09)

Comment: If you do this, I will not use your app. This is a general rule: screw with my user-browser interaction semantics and I will be unhappy. Very unhappy.

Comment: Why cant u use google to find such basic answers??? You have pretty good reputation and we expect u to google it before posting a question in a site like Stackoverflow..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That depends on the users browser settings.  You can't control that as far as I know.  All you can do is get it to open in a new windows, but if the user has his/her browser setup to open new windows in a new tab, it will do that.

So basically, the best you can do is open in a new window.

```
target="_blank"
```

i.e.

```
<a href="url here" target="_blank">link text here</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Most browsers treat a _blank target as opening in a new tab.

Set the target to _blank:

```
<a href="mypage.aspx" target="_blank"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `target` attribute set to `_blank`:

```
<a href="http://example.com" target="_blank">example</a>
```

The exact behavior depends on the browser and user settings, so this is the best one can do.

Comment: it also depends on the browser settings...not this cut and dry.

Comment: _new is actually a named window.  If you click the link again with the existing window open, it will reload in that window as though you'd named it 'myPopup'.  `_blank` forces a new one each time.

Comment: @Michael Shimmins - True enough. Answer corrected.

Answer (score 0):

This is considered bad practive because you (the web developer) is trying to control what the users browser is doing. It should be up to *me* how I want to open the link. Other than that lecture (and I understand that this may not be your decision), it doesn't seem that there is a way to do this.