# How do you open a new tab in chrome using HTML/JS?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, tabs

I tried this code

`window.open('page2.html','_newtab');`

And all it opened was a new window. How do I open a new tab?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Programmatically open new pages on Tabs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/427479/programmatically-open-new-pages-on-tabs)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a browser setting and not something you can control with code.  In my browser, your "window.open" will open a new tab, because that's what I have mine set up to do.  In others' browsers, it might open a new window.

Comment: Oops, looks like you answered with the same link before I hit "Post Answer" :-)

Comment: Where is this setting?

Comment: @BurakKarakuş - every browser is different.  Some browsers offer the ability to choose, some don't, and some (Chrome I believe) only have the ability through the use of Extensions/addons...etc..

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily. See the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14866842/1253428).

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you can, from HTML / Javascript, indicate that a page should be opened in a new tab.

*(In fact, your page might be opened to a new window, or to a new tab, depending on the configuration of the browser)*