# window.open() Opens as popup in chrome, But I need it to be open in another tab instead

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a timeout function call, inside that I want to trigger a " window.open(redir_URL,"_blank"); " which should open in a new tab, but its opening as a popup.

Also its not user initalted event, its a javascript call.

Ref: http://upshots.org/javascript/window-open-opening-in-popups-vs-new-tabs-with-set

With ref to this, I tried to trigger a click event , but that also opens as a popup.

Any one please help me out this?

Chromium ticket: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=20189

Comment: Have you tried as suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11384018/2039657) ?

Comment: Please Refer this link [Chromium Ticket for this ](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=20189)

Comment: @marbor3 yeah, I have tried that

Answer (score 0):

This is a browser setting and not something you can control with code. In my browser, your "window.open" will open a new tab, because that's what I have mine set up to do. In others' browsers, it might open a new window.

Reference:[How do you open a new tab in chrome using HTML/JS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5495328/how-do-you-open-a-new-tab-in-chrome-using-html-js)