# Open a new link in new tab in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to open a link in a new tab on ajax success, but the link opens in a new window. How to forcefully open the link in a tab rather than in a new window in chrome with jquery or javascript.

Code:

```
$("#A1").click(function (event) {
    $.ajax({ 
        type: "POST", 
        url: "Home.aspx/btnTestProject", 
        data: "{'preview':'" + inventory + "' }", 
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", 
        datatype: "json", 
        cache: false, 
        success: function (response) { 
            window.open("TestnRun.aspx"); //opens in new window 
        }    
    }); 

    window.open("TestnRun.aspx"); //opens in new tab 
});
```

Comment: What code are you using now? Same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/427479/programmatically-open-new-pages-on-tabs

Comment: $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "btnTestProject",
                    data: "{'preview':'" + inventory + "' }",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    datatype: "json",
                    cache: false,
                    success: function (response) {window.open(url)}});

Comment: No I meant what code are you using to open the window. The ajax-code is pretty irrelevant.

Comment: i am using jquery with c# in asp.net

Comment: Are you using `window.open` or something else to **open the new window**? Regardless, the answer's in the other question. It's not up to you but the user of the browser.

Comment: when i remove window.open(url) and put outside of the success of ajax call, then the links opens in new tab, but with ajax success call link opens in new window.

Comment: $("#A1").click(function (event) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "Home.aspx/btnTestProject",
                    data: "{'preview':'" + inventory + "' }",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    datatype: "json",
                    cache: false,
                    success: function (response) {
     window.open("TestnRun.aspx"); //opens in new window
                    } 
                });
                window.open("TestnRun.aspx"); //opens in new tab
            });

Answer (score 2):

In general you cannot control it. As this is user preference to open link with target="_blank" in new window or tab.

When browsers starts supporting css-3 completely then you will be having an option in future:

http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/WD-css3-hyperlinks-20040224/#target-new

You can use this:

```
#anchorId { target-new: tab ! important }
```

Comment: Off topic: but why would they put that in **CSS**?! It has pretty much absolutely **nothing** to do with presentation?

Comment: @powerbuoy: I had similar thought that why this is in CSS, this should be part of html5 specification I just checked html5 specification but there is still nothing like target-new or target ="_tab"

Comment: @powerbuoy : I put an question on SO itself for this, lets seewe might get some enlightenment from experts : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10025053/css-3-target-new-and-html5-target-blank-for-opening-in-new-tab

Comment: Nice :) ppk mentions another property wrongly added to CSS here: http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2009/09/the_html5_drag.html#link10 (it would make much more sense as an HTML attribute)

Comment: Actually it could be very useful to be able to open all links of a given class in tabs vs windows - `a.internal { target-new:tab } a.external { target-new:window }`. I can also see that being used very, very incorrectly & causing more complicated window/tab option logic in browsers...

Answer (score 2):

I saw the same thing.

And I've noted that (I'm using jquery.1.9.1):

if you call $.ajax in async, or % the browser (Chrome) open in NEW WINDOW, else if you run a JSON call **SYNC** the window will be **open tabbed**!

This open in a NEW WINDOW, pop-up:

```
  $.ajax({ url: "/cliFindExist/", 
    async: true, 
    function(data){... 
    window.open("some.aspx","_blank")});
```

This open window TABBED

```
$.ajax({ url: "/cliFindExist/", 
async: false, // <<<<<<<<<<<<< NOTE
function(data){... 
window.open("some.aspx","_blank")});
```

JQuery may be change the way/context when it call the function? depending if it run a sync or an async call.

Answer (score 1):

Use target "_blank" like this

```
<a href="http://www.google.it" target="_blank">My link</a>
```

or with Javascript like this

```
<button onclick="window.open('http://www.google.it','_blank')">Button</button>
```

Comment: He's trying to open a new page in a tab using JavaScript. This won't help.

Comment: It's similar, the important thing is to set the target value, I update the answer with the two examples.

Comment: Yes, I think the problem the OP has is that it opens in a new window though, and he wants it to open in a tab: "How to forcefully open the link in a tab rather than in a new window".