# CSS-3 'target-new' and html5 target='_blank' for opening in new tab

Tags: html, css

I was looking into a solution for opening a page in new tab and then i landed on the CSS-3 property  [target-new](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/WD-css3-hyperlinks-20040224/#target-new)

It states that: "If a user wanted to have new windows open in new tabs instead, she could use the following user style sheet to do so:

*{ target-new: tab ! important }"

I have couple of questions on it:

- How it functions internally?
- Why we don't have a property like target="_tab" in html5 specification but had this property as opening a link in new tab doesn't have any direct relation with Presentation?

Comment: Note that this is a **draft** that hasn't been updated in **six years** with the following warning: *This is the first draft of the CSS3 Hyperlink Presentation Module. It is published to get some early feedback. The properties in it and even the scope of the draft are still very unstable. The draft may be dropped or merged with another.*

Comment: "How it functions internally?" — That is up to the browser implementor.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> How it functions internally?

No browser has implemented this yet.

> Why we don't have a property like `target="_tab"` in html5 specification but had this property as opening a link in new tab doesn't have any direct relation with Presentation?

`target=_blank` is still allowed because of backwards compatibility. Introducing new reserved target values, like `_tab`, wouldn’t work the same across browsers.

IMHO, the decision should be left to the user, and web authors shouldn’t force `target=_blank` or `target-new: tab|window`.

Comment: You'r right - one should let the user decide. But there are cases out there, where you don't want it. For example when opening a Facebook sharing dialog, you might want it as extra window, because it looks horrible in a full-sized one :)

Answer (score 2):

There is a legitimate reason for using Target=_blank that everybody has completely overlooked, and that is when a website is written as a BOOK with chapters/pages and the Table of Contents must remain intact without using the BACK button to reload the previous page (Table of Contents).  This way all a surfer needs to do is close the Target Page when finished reading and they will be back to the Table of Contents.
  Lucky for us that HTML5 has reinstated the Target="_blank" code, but unfortunately the "Block Popups" must be unchecked for it to work.

Comment: Everyone thinks they have a legitimate reason for doing this, but I'm pretty sure they're all wrong. Users know how to use a back button. They know how to (hold control or) right-click to open in a new tab. Let the user choose.