# Add target="_blank" in CSS

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I have external links in the top menu of my website.

I want to open these links in new tabs. I could achieve it using `target=_blank` in HTML. **Is there a similar CSS property or anything else?**

Comment: I wouldn't think there would be a construct in CSS for this.  Links and their targets are a construct of the HTML markup, or functionality within JavaScript code at most.  CSS is about the visual styling, not so much about the behavior.

Comment: This is what i am thinking. But just wanted to share with you guys,thanks David

Comment: @David but we already have things like `pointer-events`, which are just one step away from what Mubeen asks ;)

Comment: CSS3 defines hyperlink presentation. However, I have never used it or investigated its compatibility. http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/WD-css3-hyperlinks-20040224/#the-target-new

Comment: @showdev: Interesting.  I guess there are features in CSS3 which are invalidating "you can't do that in CSS" answers just like HTML5 has been invalidating a lot of "you can't do that in HTML" answers :)

Comment: @showdev W3C Working Draft 24 February **2004** ... like many CSS specs, this had not taken off, too

Comment: @c69 True. According to [other answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10025053/css-3-target-new-and-html5-target-blank-for-opening-in-new-tab#10025155), no browser has implemented css targets.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Unfortunately, no.
In 2013, there is no way to do it with pure CSS.

---

***Update**: thanks to [showdev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/924299) for linking to the obsolete spec of [CSS3 Hyperlinks](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-hyperlinks/), and yes, no browser has implemented it. So the answer still stands valid.*

Comment: There's no way to do it with CSS *period*.

Comment: Unfortunately? This is a behaviour, not a style.

Comment: CSS has add this behavior "target-new:tab;" unfortunately all browsers sleep and have not implemented this behavior yet.
Source: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_target-new.asp

Comment: @Den - Suppose you're unsure if you want your website to open links in a new tab or the same tab by default, so you'd like to be able to change all your anchor tags in a central location in case you change your mind later. If you're building your site as part of some company's domain like Blogger, you may not have access to Mojtaba's `head` solution and would therefore rely on CSS styles. It's unfortunate to not be able to do this.

Answer (score 111):

As c69 mentioned there is no way to do it with pure CSS.

but you can use HTML instead:

use

```
<head>
    <base target="_blank">
</head>
```

in your HTML `<head>` tag for making all of page links which **not** include `target` attribute to be opened in a new blank window by default.
otherwise you can set target attribute for each link like this:

```
    <a href="/yourlink.html" target="_blank">test-link</a>
```

and it will override

```
<head>
    <base target="_blank">
</head>
```

tag if it was defined previously.

Comment: Nice! I had the same problem as the OP. WordPress theme that was opening links in the current tab. I edited the page HTML and threw in your code - didn't even know you COULD edit the head in that way in WP - and it worked! Awesome.

Comment: It's been asked for CSS, this is not CSS!

Comment: In ASP.NET this did what I wanted but had the unintended consequence that my form created a new tab every time I posted back, so I had to set the 'target' of the form explicitly <form id="form1" runat="server" target ="_self">

Comment: also see [<base>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base)

Answer (score 13):

There are a few ways CSS can 'target' navigation.
This will style internal and external links using attribute styling, which could help signal visitors to what your links will do.

```
a[href^="#"] { color: forestgreen; font-weight: normal; }
a[href^="http"] { color: dodgerblue; font-weight: normal; }
```

You can also target the traditional inline HTML 'target=_blank'.

```
a[target=_blank] { font-weight: bold; }
```

Also :target selector to style navigation block and [element targets] [1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors/Using_the_%3Atarget_pseudo-class_in_selectors).

```
nav { display: none; }
nav:target { display: block; }
```

CSS :target pseudo-class selector is supported - [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_selectors_target), [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_target.asp), [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:target).

```
a[href^="http"] { target: new; target-name: new; target-new: tab; }
```

CSS/CSS3 '[target-new](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_target-new.asp)' property etc, not supported by any major browsers, 2017 August, though it is part of the [W3 spec since 2004 February](https://www.w3.org/TR/2004/WD-css3-hyperlinks-20040224/).

[W3Schools 'modal' construction](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_target.asp), uses ':target' pseudo-class that could contain WP navigation. You can also add HTML [rel="noreferrer and noopener](https://www.thesitewizard.com/html-tutorial/open-links-in-new-window-or-tab.shtml) beside target="_blank" to improve **'new tab'** performance. CSS will not open links in tabs for now, but [this page](http://www.stylinwithcss.com/blog/post.php?s=2013-02-11-make-external-links-open-in-new-windows) explains how to do that with jQuery (compatibility may depend for [WP coders](https://allyssabarnes.com/open-external-links-new-tab/)).
MDN has a good review at [Using the :target pseudo-class in selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors/Using_the_:target_pseudo-class_in_selectors)

Answer (score 3):

Another way to use `target="_blank"` is:

```
onclick="this.target='_blank'"
```

Example:

```
<a href="http://www.url.com" onclick="this.target='_blank'">Your Text<a>
```

Comment: if you are able to insert this `onclick` attribute, you could have just as well put `target='_blank'` directly, no?

Comment: Thanks this helped me defeat bootstraps external class auto targeting _blank

Answer (score 2):

This is actually javascript but related/relevant because .querySelectorAll targets by CSS syntax:

```
var i_will_target_self = document.querySelectorAll("ul.menu li a#example")
```

this example uses css to target links in a menu with id = "example"

that creates a variable which is a collection of the elements we want to change, but we still have actually change them by setting the new target ("_blank"):

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
i_will_target_self[i].target = "_blank";
}
```

That code assumes that there are 5 or less elements. That can be changed easily by changing the phrase "i < 5."

read more here: http://xahlee.info/js/js_get_elements.html

Comment: Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("a.someClass")).forEach(function(a) { a.target = "_blank"; });

Comment: @robert4 May as well pass it directly to `forEach()` than using `slice()` on it.

Comment: or even `Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("a.something")).forEach((a) => { a.target = "_blank"; });`

Answer (score 1):

While waiting for the adoption of CSS3 targeting by the major browsers, one could run the following [`sed`](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html) command once the (X)HTML has been created:

```
sed -i 's|href="http|target="_blank" href="http|g' index.html
```

It will add `target="_blank"` to all external hyperlinks. Variations are also possible.

**EDIT**

I use this [at the end of the `makefile`](http://hamwaves.com/pandoc/index/en/makefile) which generates every web page on my site.