# Only CSS to open link in a new tab

Tags: css, wordpress

Hello I have the following problem: I have my website made in Wordpress, and I have a 3D Cover Carousel plugin there, which shows me a gallery of photos in 3d. The thing is that when I click on the image I want the link to be opened in a NEW tab. In the plugin settings there are no such an option. The plugin html is a short code added to my page. So the only thing I can change is Additional css. So is there any options to make a link be opened in a new tab only with css?

Comment: No...CSS can't initiate actions. It only **styles** elements. You need JS. Also forcing a new tab is not to be encouraged. It should be left to the user's preprogative.

Comment: i know but i dont decide this..

Comment: None of us have the power to decide that. Only W3C does :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add target="\_blank" in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17281486/add-target-blank-in-css)

Comment: Google "reverse tabnabbing" to learn about the hazard of automatically opening links in new tabs. And the fix for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.getElementById("element").setAttribute("target", "_blank");
```

You can add this piece of js in your footer.php file.

Another method is to add a js file and include it using `wp_enqueue_script` function in your function.php file.

Comment: okay i have entered in FTP and into plugin directory and changed the custom.js and it worked!

Comment: Great! Good to hear that.

Answer (score 3):

As it was previously stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17281527), there is no way to do this with pure CSS.

If you can use JavaScript, you can target the item and add it the attribute `target="_blank"`.

`document.getElementById("element").setAttribute("target", "_blank");`

Comment: But where do i add javascript in Wordpress?

Comment: I'm not so familiar with wordpress, see if [this](https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/learn-how-to-add-custom-javascript-to-wordpress-the-right-way/) or [this](https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-easily-add-javascript-in-wordpress-pages-or-posts/) helps.

Comment: okay i have entered in FTP and into plugin directory and changed the custom.js and it worked!