# Open links from a specifc <form> or <div> in new tab

Tags: html

Is there a possibility to open all links in a `<form>` or a `<div>` in a new tab?
I know there is the  `target="_blank"` but is there a possibility to do this with all links?

Answer (score 0):

You can write a simple script to do that. Get all anchor tags, iterate and set target as blank programatically.

```
 <script>
  var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
  for (let item of elements) {
    item.setAttribute("target", "_blank")
  }
 </script>
```

Comment: Yes, but only inside a specifc form or div?

Comment: var elements = document.querySelectorAll("#myId a");
          for (let item of elements) {
             item.setAttribute("target", "_blank")
          }  
where myId is the id of your div or form

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no native way of doing this. 
However, we can apply our own logic with some simple jQuery/js

<sup>**Note** StackOverflow's sandbox doesn't allow popups in snippets due to the `allow-popups` permission</sup>

**jQuery:**

```js
// For each <a> inside a <form>
$('form a').each(function (i, el) {

  // Set target=_blank
  $(el).attr("target","_blank");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <a href="https://google.com">Google</a>
  <a href="https://twitter.com">Twitter</a>
</form>
```

**JS**

```js
// All <forms>
var forms = document.getElementsByTagName('form');
Array.prototype.slice.call(forms).forEach(function (form) {
  
  // All <a>
  var links = form.getElementsByTagName('a');
  Array.prototype.slice.call(links).forEach(function (link) {
  
      // Set target=_blank
      link.setAttribute("target", "_blank")
  })
});
```

```html
<form>
  <a href="https://google.com">Google</a>
  <a href="https://twitter.com">Twitter</a>
</form>
```

---

You can customize the above by changing the hard `form` or `getElementsByTagName('form')` to something more specific, like a class selector, or maybe even an id.

---

Applying `target=_blank` through CSS would simply this, but it [doesn't seem implemented yet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17281486/add-target-blank-in-css).