# Is there a way to simulate a Ctrl-press every time the left-mouse is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I've got a problem with Internet Explorer.
As you might know FireFox and Google Chrome open links in new tabs, if the links `target="_blank"`.
But this won't work in Internet Explorer.

Due to InternetExplorers standard-options it opens every link in a new popupwindow. If you wanna open links in a new tab you have to change the setting in the options or press 'ctrl' every time you click a link.

So now my question: is there a way to simulate a Ctrl-press every time the left-mouse is clicked?

Comment: I'd say that it's none of your business. :) IE users are used to that behavior and are either dealing with it or they don't care. Don't mess with the standard behavior.

Comment: Duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/427479/programmatically-open-new-pages-on-tabs

Comment: @deceze -- unless this is an intranet web app he's working on and the boss asked him to ensure that any new window needs to open in a new tab, to alleviate help-desk calls about running out of memory bcoz users on the floor don't close windows after themselves.  Just trying to make a point that anything is possible =)

Comment: As @deceze's said, changing the end-user's browser's default behavior is usually frowned upon, unless it's really necessary.

Comment: @Beemer In that case you should rather change the browser defaults or the browser, since this problem would affect all pages on teh intarwebs.

Comment: @deceze Thanks for your answers first.But IE-User are using tabs all time. if you do a right-click on a link there is also the posebility to open the link in a new tab. Besides that the website would be much faster, if the link had been opened in a new tab. Yes maybe the IE-Users are going to hate me for this but i need to open the links in a new tab and therefor i need to simulate a ctrl-press. has anyone an idea?

Comment: @chriswilliams111 I don't think you understand his point. IE works in a certain way, which IE users are used to. *IF* you could change the behaviour just for your website, then your website would behave differently than every other website, and the browser won't operate as the user expects. That doesn't help people, that confuses people.

Comment: *"but i need to open the links in a new tab"* - No, you don't. *You* would *prefer* if links opened in a tab instead of a new window, but there's no technical reason why they *can't* open in a new window, which is the expected default behavior of IE. If you're an IE user and you don't like that behavior, use a different browser or change the default settings. If you're simply the creator of a website, why do think you can dictate a different default behavior for only your website?

Answer (score 2):

This behaviour is managed by internet explorer in its own way.

If the user wants something different he can configure the browser to behave like you are suggesting. So my straight answer is "it's not your concern" but IE or user's concern.

The only workaround I can suggest you is to open the link in the same page and live to the intelligence of user the right click/open in a nw tab action.