# Opening a new tab in firefox with Watir Webdriver

Tags: javascript, ruby, webdriver, watir

I am trying to open a new tab in firefox with Watir Webdriver (javascript is on):

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'watir-webdriver'
browser = Watir::Browser.new :ff, :profile => "default" 
browser.goto "http://google.com"
browser.execute_script("window.open('http://yahoo.com','_newtab')")
```

I followed the method on this page: [Programmatically open new pages on Tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/427479/programmatically-open-new-pages-on-tabs) 
But it opens a new window, instead of opening a new tab. What can I do to open only a new tab and not a new window? Or any other method to open a new tab?

Comment: I managed to investigate that some of the profile options of Firefox need to be modified, like something similar:
`profile['browser.link.open_newwindow']=?`

and/or

`profile['browser.link.open_newwindow.restriction']=?`

they are described here: [link](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Browser.link.open_newwindow)

Comment: Why do you care if the new page is opened in a tab or in a window?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, and I've struggled for a day until I found it's a known Selenium issue:
http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=3380

Apparently, Selenium doesn't support opening links in a new tab, only a new window.