# Opening a link in new tab

Tags: javascript, asp.net, window.open

I am using an imagebutton to send the ID of a project as a command argument. In a window, I only display one picture and that's the imagebutton. When that image is clicked I want to open the related project's all pictures in a new tab.

With this code on code behind,

```
int ID = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "", string.Format("yenipencere = window.open('Projeresim.aspx?ProjeID={0}','_blank')", ID), true);
```

I can manage this beautifully in Firefox and Internet Explorer, but Chrome insists on opening it as a pop-up. Is there any way I can make this happen in Chrome as well or is it a default Chrome setting?

I know I could use other linking methods, but I need to send an ID as a parameter.

Comment: You can't, thats browsers settings.

Comment: This is possible a duplicate from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-url-in-new-tab-using-javascript)

Comment: Actually, I can. I can make this work with a href target = "_blank" even in chrome. The problem is I need to send a parameter, and yes it is a similar question to your link marcus but they don't have the answer I need.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Programmatically open new pages on Tabs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/427479/programmatically-open-new-pages-on-tabs)