# Chrome opens a new window + a tab when i try to Process.Start(url)

Tags: c#, google-chrome

I want to open a url in a new tab in Chrome. It worked with `Process.Start(url);` before but now it opens the tab along with a new tab in a new window. I also tried with `Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe", url);`, but it does the same.

Any solution for this?

Comment: Did you try what happens when you execute `chrome.exe` from the command line using the same parameters? If this shows the same behavior, your problem is probably in Chrome itself and not in your code.

Comment: When i start it from the command prompt without any parameter sometimes it opens one window, sometimes it opens two new windows. When i start it with a parameter it's the same as my question, it opens the tab and also a new window...

Comment: In that case, your problem is in Chrome and completely unrelated to C#. I can't reproduce the behavior here, so it's probably a local issue on your workstation.

Comment: according to http://www.ericdlarson.com/misc/chrome_command_line_flags.html and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/427479/programmatically-open-new-pages-on-tabs ; its not possible to do