# Google chrome opens new window instead of new tab

Tags: asp.net

Google chrome opens new window instead of new tab when I am using the below code

```
public static void OpenPageinNewTab(this TemplateControl page, string Url, Page CurrentPage)
{
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(
        page,
        page.GetType(),
        "OpenPage",
        "javascript:window.open('" + CurrentPage.ResolveClientUrl(Url) + "');",
        true
    );
}
```

Except Google chrome all other browsers open new tab with the above code

Comment: possible duplicate of [Open url in new tab using javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-url-in-new-tab-using-javascript)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Programmatically open new pages on Tabs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/427479/programmatically-open-new-pages-on-tabs)

Answer (score 0):

This previous question should provide some insight into your problem and provide you with a suitable answer: 
[Programmatically open new pages on Tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/427479/programmatically-open-new-pages-on-tabs)

It isnt the developers role to decide if its a new tab or new window thats down to the user.