# Open in new tab instead of new _blank window

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

`<a href='#' onclick="loadpage();">[RANDOM PAGE]</a>`

I call the following function on click.

```
function loadpage(){
$.ajax
({
type: "POST",
url: "fetchpage.php",
data: "showpage=1",
success: function(msg)
{
window.open(msg);
}
});
}
```

The ajax call returns a URL, `msg` which should be opened in a new tab.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Programmatically open new pages on Tabs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/427479/programmatically-open-new-pages-on-tabs)

Answer (score 2):

I think it depends on the browser config. JS can't control it.

Answer (score 0):

How about :

```
$('body').append('<a id="newTab" target="_new" href="http://......></a>');
$('#newTab').click();
```

Comment: `_new` is not a valid syntax

Comment: @RápliAndrás Ok. Not sure where I picked that up from. Seems it should be `_blank`

Answer (score 0):

You can not do this. Even if you can, all the browser does not works! IE!!!

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do it which works on all modern browsers (including IE7+):

```
function loadpage(a){
$.ajax
({
type: "POST",
url: "fetchpage.php",
data: "showpage=1",
success: function(msg)
{
a.href=msg;
a.rel='nofollow';
a.target='_blank';
}
});
}
```

and

```
<a href='#' onmouseover="loadpage(this);">[RANDOM PAGE]</a>
```

Comment: Because browsers know that you have clicked an `<a>` link, which is based on user interaction, so they wont detect a spammy popup or open a new blank window.