# Programatically open the URL in new tab in chromium browser using javascript

Tags: javascript, popupwindow, chromium

I have a web application where I have four/five icons in the default page. On click of these icons i am redirecting to some URL in new tab of already opened chromium browser instance using javascript. Below is the javascript code snippet that I am using to launch the URL in new tab of already opened chromium browser instance. Here I am manually clicking the icon

```
window.open(myURL, '_blank');
```

But the issue is when I am trying to open the same URL using the same code and programatically triggering the same code to open the URL in new tab, it opes up as a Pop Up but not in a tab. Below is how I am trying to pragmatically open the URL. I am calling the click event of the Icon in the default page using some script rather than manually clicking the icon.

```
$('#myIconId').click();
```

If somebody could please help me out. TIA

Comment: I could not reproduce your problem... http://jsbin.com/ELAGEcud/1/edit

Answer (score 0):

give a try to use

```
<a href="some url" target="_newtab">content of the anchor</a>
```

Although You shouldn't force user to open new pages or new tab without showing them a hint on what is going to happen before they click on the link.

Above code may or may not work on all browser, please test before making live.

UPDATE

Ref : [Programmatically open new pages on Tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/427479/programmatically-open-new-pages-on-tabs)

Comment: I don't think `_newtab` is some modifier attribute. You may very well use `_blahblah`.

Comment: Thanks for the link. (1) that link is not a reference, just an answer on another question i.e. it is not authoritative. (2) did you read the last comment on that answer? ;)