# Open link in new tab in react router programmatically

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am using ReactJS for a project along with React Router (no redux) I want to programmatically open a link but on a new tab. I am aware that using 
  `onClickNode={e => this.props.history.push('/${e.data.node.id}')}` I can go to the desired link but the problem is that it gets opened in the same tab. Also there is no way to use JSX in that function and hence no possibility of adding `<Link>` component.

( I am using React Router v4)

Comment: This can help even if they don't use react
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/427479/programmatically-open-new-pages-on-tabs

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Programmatically open new pages on Tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/427479/programmatically-open-new-pages-on-tabs)

Answer (score 93):

This https://stackoverflow.com/a/11384018/7697399 answer helped me out and worked flawlessly. This could be done without the help of react-router.

```
function openInNewTab(url) {
  var win = window.open(url, '_blank');
  win.focus();
}
```

Comment: I'm getting `Uncaught TypeError: win.focus is not a function`

Comment: Awesome! Worked great. The solution worked for me without needing win.focus() though.

Comment: It's blocked by firefox and safari

Answer (score 20):

Similar to the previous answer, but doesn't error out if the window couldn't be opened.

```
function open(url) {
  const win = window.open(url, '_blank');
  if (win != null) {
    win.focus();
  }
}
```

Comment: `win?.focus()`?

Answer (score 7):

`<Link/>` component from `react-router-dom` can be used. Using you can pass props to new tab.

```
<Link to='/' target="_blank"> 
  <div> Button </div>
 </Link>
```

Answer (score 7):

In new Javascript syntax you could write the function like so:

```
const openLink = (url) => window.open(url, '_blank')?.focus();
```

This will try to open the URL in a new tab and focus on it if succeeded.
It will not throw an error if the tab did not open.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the path programatically using `useHref` hook([Docs](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/hooks/use-href)). This is what the `<Link>` component internally [uses](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/main/packages/react-router-dom/index.tsx#L275). You can then open it in new tab using `window.open`. This would automatically add the basename etc for you.

```js
let href = useHref(to);
window.open(href, '_blank');
```